# Javascript JQuery-like library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to mimic a JQuery library (for learning purposes) and I'm stuck with the following:

```
function _(id){
var about={
version:"1.0",
author:"Samson"
}
if (this===window)
    return new _(id);
if (!id) 
    return about;
if (typeof id=="string")
    this.element=document.getElementById(id);
else
    this.element=id;

return this;
}

_.prototype={
    append:function(str){
        this.element.innerHTML+=str;
        return this;
    },
    post:function(url){
        alert('posting to: '+url);
    }
}
```

I can use this like this:

```
_("a1").append(' deescription');
```

But I want to be able to use the post function without invoking the constructor :

```
_.post('url') //post is in the prototype but is undefined because the constructor is not called right?
```

Comment: @arxanas It is in the sense that it has mechanisms for extension. I'd call it a library, but the plugin and extensibility bits are frameworky. In any case, OP is saying *they're* building a framework, not that jQuery is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to define `post` on `_` itself, not its prototype.

```
_.post = function(url) { ... }
```

Comment: No problem, JS is a very flexible language and you can mold it in many ways (one reason why I like it so much). But it can be a little much to wrap around at times.